# Enable editing in UITextview

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextview

I am very confused by the following issue, i have a `UITextView`, all set up in exactly the same way. However i'am not able to enter anything

Comment: it is can be under translucent view

Comment: sometimes happens, that above your textview can lay another view with clear background color. in this case you cannot tap on textview and begin editing, because you actualy tapping on this translucent view. but its only my assumption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

[textView setEditable:YES]

[image]

Comment: You have used .xib or you have added it programmatically?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot with properties on the left. That should help to understand better.

Comment: Check if the view in which the textview is added, the user interaction is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Is the property "Enabled" checked under the attribute inspector? Also is User Interaction enabled?

Comment: selectable, editable and userInteraction are all checked

Comment: Is it possible that your text field is sitting under another layer?